# How to show audio waveforms in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, audio, mobile

I am using the [audio waveforms](https://pub.dev/packages/audio_waveforms) package in Flutter. But the waves it shows have a very low amplitude. The difference in the change in waveforms is not very noticeable. So how can I increase the amplitude to increase the fluctuations in amplitude in waves when the user records and plays audio? Is there any other package that can help? I tried using the flutter_sound package, and audio recording is working fine, but how do I show a waveform using this?

Comment: Could you give us the sound file you're using in the package?

Comment: @DharamBudh You want the code of audio file??

Comment: Sure, source code with source audio file.